# Best Practice for include JS file with custom variables

Tags: javascript, datatable

I have a javascript that I want to put into a file and then load it on all pages that have datatables.  My question is that some of my datatables have custom variables in the JS file.  What would be the best practice to have this file load and then also load the page-specific variables?

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#datascape').DataTable( {
          responsive: true,
          columnDefs: [
            { responsivePriority: 10001, targets: 1 },
            { responsivePriority: 10001, targets: 7 },
            { responsivePriority: 10001, targets: 8 },
            { responsivePriority: 10001, targets: 9 },
            { responsivePriority: 10001, targets: 11 },
            { responsivePriority: 10001, targets: 12 },
            { responsivePriority: 10001, targets: 13 },
            { responsivePriority: 10001, targets: 14 },
            { responsivePriority: 2, targets: -2 },
            { responsivePriority: 1, targets: 10 }
        ],
          lengthChange: true,
          pageLength: 15,
          language: {
          search: "_INPUT_",
          searchPlaceholder: "Search Records"
              },
          dom: '<"top"i>rt<"bottom"flp><"clear">',
          dom: 'Bfrtip',
          pagingType: "full_numbers",

            buttons: [
                { extend: 'csvHtml5',
                footer: true,
                text:   'Download   <img src="/assets/images/icons/download.svg" class="downimage">',
                filename: function(){
                           var d = new Date();
                           month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
                           day = '' + d.getDate(),
                           year = d.getFullYear();
                           var n = d.getTime();
                           var now = new Date();
                           var months = ['JAN', 'FEB', 'MAR', 'APR', 'MAY', 'JUN', 'JUL', 'AUG', 'SEP', 'OCT', 'NOV', 'DEC'];
                           var formattedDate = now.getFullYear() + months[now.getMonth()] + now.getDate();
                           return formattedDate + 'Site Download'}

               },
            ],

        });
    });
```

This would be the custom attribute I am talking about

```
          columnDefs: [
            { responsivePriority: 10001, targets: 1 },
            { responsivePriority: 10001, targets: 7 },
            { responsivePriority: 10001, targets: 8 },
            { responsivePriority: 10001, targets: 9 },
            { responsivePriority: 10001, targets: 11 },
            { responsivePriority: 10001, targets: 12 },
            { responsivePriority: 10001, targets: 13 },
            { responsivePriority: 10001, targets: 14 },
            { responsivePriority: 2, targets: -2 },
            { responsivePriority: 1, targets: 10 }
        ],
```

If something like this was possible?  I know this wont work as I tried it but thats the idea.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/datascapejs/datatable.js">


columnDefs: [
  { responsivePriority: 10001, targets: 1 },
  { responsivePriority: 10001, targets: 7 },
  { responsivePriority: 10001, targets: 8 },
  { responsivePriority: 10001, targets: 9 },
  { responsivePriority: 10001, targets: 11 },
  { responsivePriority: 10001, targets: 12 },
  { responsivePriority: 10001, targets: 13 },
  { responsivePriority: 10001, targets: 14 },
  { responsivePriority: 2, targets: -2 },
  { responsivePriority: 1, targets: 10 }
],

});
});

</script>
```

And this is the datascape.js file

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#datascape').DataTable( {
      responsive: true,

      lengthChange: true,
      pageLength: 15,
      language: {
      search: "_INPUT_",
      searchPlaceholder: "Search Records"
          },
      dom: '<"top"i>rt<"bottom"flp><"clear">',
      dom: 'Bfrtip',
      pagingType: "simple_numbers",

        buttons: [
            { extend: 'csvHtml5',
            footer: true,
            text:   'Download   <img src="/assets/images/icons/download.svg" class="downimage">',
            filename: function(){
                       var d = new Date();
                       month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
                       day = '' + d.getDate(),
                       year = d.getFullYear();
                       var n = d.getTime();
                       var now = new Date();
                       var months = ['JAN', 'FEB', 'MAR', 'APR', 'MAY', 'JUN', 'JUL', 'AUG', 'SEP', 'OCT', 'NOV', 'DEC'];
                       var formattedDate = now.getFullYear() + months[now.getMonth()] + now.getDate();
                       return formattedDate + 'datascape from RQ'}

           },
        ],
```

Now on some of my pages, it would have less or more.  Any help is appreciated.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could load the variable of columnDefs in a script element before loading your external script.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
const columnDefs = [
  { responsivePriority: 10001, targets: 1 },
  { responsivePriority: 10001, targets: 7 },
  { responsivePriority: 10001, targets: 8 },
  { responsivePriority: 10001, targets: 9 },
  { responsivePriority: 10001, targets: 11 },
  { responsivePriority: 10001, targets: 12 },
  { responsivePriority: 10001, targets: 13 },
  { responsivePriority: 10001, targets: 14 },
  { responsivePriority: 2, targets: -2 },
  { responsivePriority: 1, targets: 10 }
];
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/datascapejs/datatable.js">
```

> datatable.js

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#datascape').DataTable( {
          responsive: true,
          columnDefs,
          lengthChange: true,
          pageLength: 15,
          language: {
          search: "_INPUT_",
          searchPlaceholder: "Search Records"
              },
          dom: '<"top"i>rt<"bottom"flp><"clear">',
          dom: 'Bfrtip',
          pagingType: "full_numbers",

            buttons: [
                { extend: 'csvHtml5',
                footer: true,
                text:   'Download   <img src="/assets/images/icons/download.svg" class="downimage">',
                filename: function(){
                           var d = new Date();
                           month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
                           day = '' + d.getDate(),
                           year = d.getFullYear();
                           var n = d.getTime();
                           var now = new Date();
                           var months = ['JAN', 'FEB', 'MAR', 'APR', 'MAY', 'JUN', 'JUL', 'AUG', 'SEP', 'OCT', 'NOV', 'DEC'];
                           var formattedDate = now.getFullYear() + months[now.getMonth()] + now.getDate();
                           return formattedDate + 'Site Download'}

               },
            ],

        });
    });
```